# How to push to a new viewcontroller from slide out menu cell

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a slide out table view menu and used the modal segue to connect with second view controller. I am using navigation bar.

**FirstViewController:**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.filterTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
     UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        // Set the photo if it navigates to the PhotoView
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCatView"]) {

        catView= [navController topViewController];

        NSString *catid= [[myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"catid"];
        catView.catid = catid;
    }

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock= ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };

    }
```

**SecondViewController**

```
- (IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I'm getting error as

> reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];  I get error in last line

Comment: Hmm, that's probably not line that causes it.. catView is not nil, correct?

Comment: now this error is solved or not